# Variable not passing as an Arg [python]

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a functions based on what input is received but I'm getting an error when I try to pass the input as and arg for a function. Heres an example of what Im trying to do

```
var ='hello world'

def example(data):
    #function code

example(var)
```

thats a basic usage of what Im doing and its returning an error like

```
var is not defined
```

here is my actual code

```
import AriaAudioConfig as Ariaconfig
import AriaMathModule as AriaMath
import AriaLocationModule as AriaLocation
import AriaNLPModule as AriaNLP
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, TypeVar

location = ['geolocatecity','citydiff','locate', 'location', 'where is', 'far', 'distance']
math = ['calculate', 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'addition', 'subtraction', 'multiplication', 'division', 'square-root', 'power', 'squared', 'minus']
audio = ['volume','speak', 'sound']
nlp = ['translate', 'translation', 'language', 'english', 'spanish', 'french']
locdict = {'geolocatecity':'blabla','citydiff':'blabla'}

state = 0
city2 = 0
file = pd.read_csv('geolocations.csv')

def dataProcess(data):
    global state
    global city2
    datasearch = data.split()
    argsearch = datasearch
    datalength = len(datasearch)
    for i in range(datalength):
        if datasearch[i] in location:
            data = datasearch[i]
            datacom = typeremoval(functiongrep(AriaLocation))
            datacom = str(datacom).split()
            datalen = len(datacom)
            with open('geolocations.csv', 'rt') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
                for row in reader:
                    for field in row[0]:
                        for i in range(datalength):
                            if argsearch[i] == row[0]:
                                try:
                                    if city in locals():
                                        city2 = argsearch[i]
                                
                                except:
                                    city = argsearch[i]
                            
                            if argsearch[i] == row[1]:
                                    state = argsearch[i]
                                
                            if argsearch[i] == row[2]:
                                country = argsearch[i]
            
                f.close()
            
            for i in range(datalen):
                if str(data) in str(datacom[i]):
                    activefunction = datacom[i]
                    if state != 0:
                        eval('AriaLocation.' + activefunction +'(' + city + ',' + state + ',' + country + ')')
                    elif city2 != 0:
                        eval('AriaLocation.' + activefunction + '(' + city + ',' + city2 + ')')
                    else:
                        print('uh-oh something went wrong')
            
        elif datasearch[i] in math:
            data = datasearch[i]
            datacom = typeremoval(functiongrep(AriaMath))
            print(data)
            if data in datacom:
                print('found')
        elif datasearch[i] in audio:
            data = datasearch[i]
            datacom = typeremoval(functiongrep(Ariaconfig))
        elif datasearch[i] in nlp:
            data = datasearch[i]
            datacom = typeremoval(functiongrep(AriaNLP))

#dataProcess('Aria how far am I from Arizona')
def functiongrep(function):
    string = ''
    functions_list = [o for o in getmembers(function) if isfunction(o[1])]
    flen = len(functions_list)
    for i in range(flen):
        head, sep, tail = str(functions_list[i]).partition('<')
        string = string + head
    return string

def typeremoval(function):
    func = str(function)
    func = str(''.join(func))

    func = re.sub("[',()]", '', func)
    return func


dataProcess('locate Scottsdale Arizona USA')
```

I want dataProcess() to activate different commands based on what is given as the input.

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'Scottsdale' is not defined
File "/Users/timyc1/Desktop/DeadIdeas/smartroom/Seavernet/Aria/AriaProcessingModule.py", line 58, in dataProcess
eval('AriaLocation.' + activefunction +'(' + city + ',' + state + ',' + country + ')')
  File "/Users/timyc1/Desktop/DeadIdeas/smartroom/Seavernet/Aria/AriaProcessingModule.py", line 95, in <module>
dataProcess('locate Scottsdale Arizona USA')
```

Comment: Please share error traceback or line where the error occurs (along with the original call)

Comment: I edited my question with the error

Comment: What are you calling [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) on arbitrary strings? What do you expect that statement to do, especially given that you ignore the return value?

Comment: @Brian I am using Eval to call a function from another module it doesn't matter that I'm calling the module by string because the module is defined already

Comment: I would highly recommend for you to read something about decorators, or how functions are first class citizens in Python. Your functiongrep() will result in one long string (like 'function1function2function3', which you then feed to typeremoval(), where you are removing characters that should not be there anymore (since you used get_attributes().. Reading up on decorators might help you in this case! :)

Comment: @DjerroNeth okay will do, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval` for this. `eval` is almost never the solution.

```
if state != 0:
    getattr(AriaLocation, activefunction)(city, state, country)
elif city2 != 0:
    getattr(AriaLocation, activefunction)(city, cit2)
else:
    print('uh-oh something went wrong')
```